# Where to close FileWriter when reusing it in different methods?

Tags: java, oop, for-loop, if-statement, filewriter

I have encountered a problem: I need to be able to filewrite after I have added to the array (dock) and removed from the array (undock) on the fly. But I do not know where to put the flush() and close(). I get errors when I but it after the write function wherever I put them because they have already closed the filewriter. Can you help?

```
try {
    portLog.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
    portLog.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];
private static Ship[] waitingList = new Ship[10];
static FileWriter portLog;
static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
//get current date time with Date()
static Date date = new Date();

static {
    try {
        portLog = new FileWriter("\\Users\\Smith\\Desktop\\PortLog.txt", true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

public static void menu() {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Dock");
                dock();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Undock");
                undock();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3. Status");
                printDock();
                printWaitingList();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("4. Exit");
                System.exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
                break;
        }
    }
}


public static void dock() {

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    String size = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");
    //Check if the dock number is valid
    int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null) {
        int c = 0;
        int co = 0;
        int sco = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dock1.length; j++) {
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Cargo")) {
                c++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Container")) {
                co++;
            }
            if (dock1[j] != null && dock1[j].getShipSize().equals("Super-Container")) {
                sco++;
            }
        }

        if (c < 10 && co < 5 && sco < 2) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space you can dock");
            System.out.println("Ship has been docked");


            try {
                portLog.write("\n" + " Docked: " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " Size: " + dock1[i].getShipSize() + " at " + dateFormat.format(date));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot dock");
            waitingList(name, size);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        waitingList(name, size);
    }

}


public static void undock() {
    System.out.println("Status of ships: ");
    printDock();
    System.out.println("Enter ship's name to undock: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] != null && dock1[i].getShipName().equals(name)) {

            try {
                portLog.write("\n" + "Undocked: " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " Size: " + dock1[i].getShipSize() + " at " + dateFormat.format(date));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dock1[i] = null;
            System.out.println("Ship removed");

            /// HERE CHECK IF SHIP IN DOCK
            for (int j = 0; j < waitingList.length; j++) {
                if (dock1[i] == null && waitingList[j] != null) {
                    // Add ship to the dock
                    dock1[i] = new Ship(waitingList[j].getShipName(), waitingList[j].getShipSize());
                    System.out.println("Move ship from waiting list to dock 1");
                    waitingList[j] = null;
                    return;
                } else {
                  return;
                }
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Ship not found");
}

public static void waitingList(String name, String size) {

    System.out.println("Dock 1 is full, ship will try to be added to Waiting List");
    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            //Add ship to the dock
            waitingList[i] = new Ship(name, size);
            System.out.println("Enough space added to waiting list");
            return;
        } else {

        }
    }
    System.out.println("No space on waiting list, ship turned away.");
}

public static void printDock() {

    System.out.println("Docks:");

    for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++) {
        if (dock1[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}

private static void printWaitingList() {

    System.out.println("Waiting List:");

    for (int i = 0; i < waitingList.length; i++) {
        if (waitingList[i] == null) {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + waitingList[i].getShipName() + " " + waitingList[i].getShipSize());
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can't you close it on case 4?

Comment: Doesn't print to file

Comment: Yeah because it didn’t work what you said and I’m don’t know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

That is the thing when you are new to Java, and first start using all static variables within a single class. That is good for the first steps, and getting a hello world printed, or some simple calculations.

But then this approach quickly gets into your way. You see, in the "real" world of OOP, such code is much more of an anti-pattern.

Meaning: that is where you should starting thinking of creating classes of your own. A class has a distinct purpose, like *modelling* a *Ship*, or maybe a *Dock*. Then you add think about the properties that belong into such classes (and for sure: these fields are **not** static) then.

In that sense, the real answer here is that you "fully" step back and start thinking about **better** ways to organize the functionalities that you intend to create. As said, in your case, that boils down to define proper Ship/Dock classes. That will then allow you to *abstract* lower level details, such as "some stuff is stored in files". Because then you can have a `DockPersistenceService` class for example. Which you pass a list of Dock objects, to somehow persist them. Or that reads a list of Dock objects from a file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, like you said i'm new. I'll look into this and improve.

Comment: @S.smith94 And sure, this is not a "direct" answer. And of course you could get around this exercise for now. By somehow pushing in even more code within the current structure. But sooner or alter you will be broken, and unable to add new features - because things are tightly coupled within one huge static monolith of fields and methods. The longer you wait, the harder it will be to break that up.

Comment: Yeah this was just something to do in my spare time while I’m learning. You’re right I need to start using more classes.

Answer (score 1):

As a general principle, it's a good idea for a resource like this to have a well-defined lifetime.  That will typically mean that it's not static.  @GhostCat is right that you should really consider a more robust approach, but as a starting point, I'd suggest this.

```
public static void menu() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean keepProcessing = true;  // use this to control the loop, don't call System.exit!

    // use try-with-resources to control resource lifetime
    try (FileWriter portLog = new FileWriter("\\Users\\Smith\\Desktop\\PortLog.txt", true)) {

        while (keepProcessing) {
            int choice = scan.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1. Dock");
                    dock(portLog);
                    break;
                // Other cases skipped for brevity
                case 4:
                    keepProcessing = false;
                    break;
                // Other cases skipped for brevity
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then, have your other methods accept the portLog as a parameter.

```
public static void dock(FileWriter portLog) {
    // ...
}
```

With this setup, the `menu` method will open the portLog file when it starts up, and close it when the method is finished.  It also makes it clearer that the `dock`, `undock`, etc. methods require the use of the `FileWriter` object.

Comment: It worked fine for me, but I did have to tweak your code to consume the newline after your `scan.nextInt()` call.